# Is there a linux equivalent of the Mac OS X command "textutil"?

Tags: linux, conversion, documents

On Mac OS X there's a very handy command called `textutil`, that can be invoked from the terminal and allows to convert a document from a format to another; Sometimes I use it to convert a RTF file into HTML, but it's also able to convert doc, docx, odt and other formats.

I used to believe that it was a standard unix command, but I cannot find it and when I try to write `sudo apt-get install textutil` Ubuntu said that it have no idea of what `textutil` is... maybe I have searched in the wrong place for the command?

Do you know if something similar exists for Linux? I need to invoke that command from a script that will run on a linux server.

Comment: `textutil` relies on Cocoa frameworks, which is why it is only available for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GNU unrtf](http://www.gnu.org/s/unrtf/) does almost exclusively what you want.

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can do a lot more.

Answer (score 4):

`unoconv` can convert between OpenOffice.org document formats (ie. anything OOO can open).

> Supported document formats include Open Document Format (.odt), MS
>   Word (.doc), MS Office Open/MS OOXML (.xml), Portable Document Format
>   (.pdf), HTML, XHTML, RTF, Docbook (.xml), and more.

I know it is in the Ubuntu repository, but you can get it from, and see more info at [unoconv's homepage](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/)

Comment: `unoconv` is also in Debian. This is where Ubuntu got it from. So if you have `apt-get`, this will work on recent systems `sudo apt-get install unoconv`: